# how to restrict the users to change theme other than site admins using features in share point 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am new to sharepoint 2010. i would like to restrict the users to change theme other than site admins using feature in sharepoint 2010. I tried the below code to do the same.

```
          SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 

           { 

               SPWebApplication webApp = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWebApplication; 



               SPPolicyRole RestrictThemes; 



               //we are removing the ApplyStyleSheets permission and ApplyThemeAndBorder permission by passing this 

               //to Policyroles. 

               SPBasePermissions RestrictPermissions = SPBasePermissions.ApplyStyleSheets | SPBasePermissions.ApplyThemeAndBorder; 



               //we are not granting any permissions 

               SPBasePermissions GrantPermissions = new SPBasePermissions(); 



               RestrictThemes = webApp.PolicyRoles["Restrict Themes"]; 



               if (RestrictThemes == null) 

               { 



                   RestrictThemes = webApp.PolicyRoles.Add("Restrict Themes", "Restricts themes to be modified by anybody", 

                                                   GrantPermissions, 

                                                   RestrictPermissions); 

                   webApp.Update(); 

               } 



               SPPolicy policy = webApp.Policies.Add("NT Authority\\Authenticated users", "All Authenticated Users"); 

               policy.PolicyRoleBindings.Add(RestrictThemes); 



               webApp.Update();
```

});

But when i try this code, it isn't allowing even site admins.
Please provide any idea or suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why do this in code? The ability to apply themes is controlled by the "[Apply Themes and Borders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288074.aspx)" permission. By default this is assigned to the "Design" permission level.

Just make sure that your site's members have the proper permissions instead of trying to modify permissions for everybody. You can do that either by modifying the permissions of the default **SharePoint** site groups or by creating new groups with the desired permissions.

Furthermore, you shouldn't be assigning permissions directly to Windows groups. SharePoint doesn't treat Windows (or AD) groups the same as SharePoint groups. You can avoid a lot of pain by creating specific SP groups and assigning AD groups to them.

Comment: Thanks for your response Panagiotis. Sorry for the late response. Your solution is worked fine. I want to achieve this programmatically.I would like create Sharepoint groups programatically in feature activation. is it possible? Please suggest me on this. Correct if i am wrong.